# Select com duas condições

Tags: mysql

Como faço para selecionar os usuários que tem o código diferente de 0 e de 573?

Por exemplo, essa é minha tabela:

```
 Usuario Codigo
    1        573
    2        0
    3        0
    4        100
    5        520
```

Preciso selecionar somente os usuários que tem o código DIFERENTE de 0 e 573.

Comment: Já estudou SQL antes? Se sim, deve ter tentado fazer algo, o que foi? Poderia nos mostrar sua tentativa?

Comment: @user134546, alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema? Vote naquelas que lhe foram úteis: [Por que é importante votar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 2):

Tem duas alternativas para o fazer:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    MinhaTabela 
WHERE   Codigo <> 0 
    AND Codigo <> 573
```

Ou:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    MinhaTabela 
WHERE   Codigo NOT IN (0, 573)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE CODIGO <> 0 AND CODIGO <> 573
```